# Protecting a mutable object from changing in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm trying to do some defensive programming here to avoid objects changing state in a way that is not easy to debug, so given that in Python the following is possible is there a way to protect Foo.name from being changed so that it forces me to do it more explicitly?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def rename(self, new_name):
        self.foo.name = new_name

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo('Fooname')
    print 'A foo instance is born and baptized as %s' % foo.name
    ainstance = A(foo)
    print 'The foo instance is then passed to A and is still called %s' % foo.name
    binstance = B(foo)
    print 'But then the foo instance is passed to B'
    binstance.foo.name = 'Barname'
    print 'And in B it is renamed to %s' % foo.name
```

This outputs:

```
A foo instance is born and baptized as Fooname
The foo instance is then passed to A and is still called Fooname
But then the foo instance is passed to B
And in B it is renamed to Barname
```

I know I could implement a method to rename Foo that I could force myself use or that I could use name mangling but this still doesn't actually prevent me from inadvertently changing `foo.name` even if it's called `foo._name`

Comment: It's also hard to protect you from disconnecting the computer and throwing it out the nearest window.

Comment: You mention `foo._name`, that's one underscore prefix.  It's not perfect, but have you tried using two underscores as a prefix? `foo.__name`

Comment: Hi cdarke, this is intentional. I believe it's a common practice in the Python world to have the benefits of the double underscore without the name mangling and adding the dependency on the class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can intercept the setting of arbitrary attributes like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __setattr__(self, attrname, value):
        print "Intercepted: " + attrname + " attribute of Foo set to " + value
        super(Foo, self).__setattr__(attrname, value)
```

That will tell you whenever someone sets any attribute of a `Foo` instance.  Obviously you can do whatever you like in `__setattr__`, up to and including aborting the program if someone sets an attribute at an unexpected time.

[Properties](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#property) are a neater way to do this for a single attribute:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def getname(self):
        return self.__name

    def setname(self, name):
        print "Intercepted: name attribute of Foo set to " + name
        self.__name = name

    name = property(getname, setname)
```

but `__setattr__` lets you intercept all attribute settings from a single place.

Comment: I think that `object.__setattr__(self,name,value)` is a little more idiomatic than `self.__dict__[name] = value`.

Comment: Better still: use `super(Foo, self).__setattr__(attrname, value)` and play nice when subclassed together with *other* base classes that override `__setattr__`.